# Hiding false noreturn syntax errors in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, noreturn

Eclipse CDT [doesn't know about the _Noreturn keyword](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386402) and shows it as a syntax error.

A suggested workaround is to add an empty preprocessor macro entry to the *CDT User Setting Entries*, but apparently this has to be done in the project settings for every single project.

Is there a way to fix this globally for all projects, other than hiding all syntax errors completely? "CDT User Setting Entries" shows up in the global preferences under *C/C++ > Build > Settings*, but apparently cannot be edited there. (using Eclipse Oxygen.3a / 4.7.3a)

Comment: if the function does not return, just declare the return type as `void` and eliminate the attribute `__noreturn__`

Answer (score 1):

On the mentioned preference page, you could edit the "Built-in Compiler Settings" provider's "Command to to get compiler specs" to add `-D_Noreturn=""`.

Then, as long as your projects are configured to use the global "Built-in Compiler Settings" provider ("Use global provider shared between projects" checked in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers tab -> Built-in Compiler Settings provider), they will pick up this macro definition.

You could also consider [contributing a fix](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) to add propert support for `_Noreturn` to CDT.